# imploding array_keys from Facebook JSON data

Tags: php, facebook

Need some help with the sample code provided the facebook.  I can't get it to return a series of IDs that I need to run a sql query against.

```
   $friends = '{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Paul",
         "id": "12000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Bonnie",
         "id": "120310"
      },
      {
         "name": "Melissa",
         "id": "120944"
      },
      {
         "name": "Simon",
         "id": "125930"
      },
      {
         "name": "Anthony",
         "id": "120605"
      },
      {
         "name": "David",
         "id": "120733"
     }
   ]
}';

$obj = json_decode($friends);
print $obj->{'data'}[0]->{'name'};
```

I can return the "Paul"

what I want is to return all the id's using implode(array_keys($obj),",")

I am only getting data to return.

What I'd like to do is retrieve all the IDs separated by a comma.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)-ing on the `data` key with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function get_id($o) {
   return $o->id;
}

implode(array_map('get_id', $obj->data),",")
```

Comment: Hi can you also let me know how I could return the index by ID, I want to use it to return the name string by ID.  Thanks, I used array_search but it kept returning null